# Unable to find a link while running Selenium Test case

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver. I can log in to the application, but while logging out it gets stuck, reason it cannot find logout link. I tried to find it byLink and byId. I have also tried using thread.sleep() but nothing seems to be working.

Logout link is present in all the pages.

HTML code:

```
<li>#{loginView.loggedInUser}>
    <ul><li><h:link value="Administration" outcome="Administration.xhtml" /></li>
    <li><h:commandLink value="Logout" actionListener="#{loginView.logout}">
      <f:param id="userName" value="#{loginView.username}" />
    </h:commandLink></li>
    </ul></li>
```

SELENIUM code:

```
Thread.sleep(5000); 

WebElement logOut = findElementByLinkText("Logout");

logOut.click();

assertEquals("Please sign in: ", findElementBySelector("h3.loginTitle.centerAlign").getText());
```

Comment: Can you paste the part of HTML where the logout link is? Also, is the logout link present on all pages?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of the HTML of the page, and also the code you are using to find it. Without this, we cannot begin to help you.

Comment: what error is it throwing? BTW did you try to record the test in Selenium IDE? When I am stuck in defining the locator, I find it by Selenium IDE and copypaste ther result to java WebDriver code

Comment: Yes, I tried with Selenium IDE too. In IDE, it is just clickAndWait and in java it uses By.linkText. The test runs smoothly and when its time to logout, it gets stuck and I've to either close the browser or move the mouse over username myself to continue log out.

Comment: hmmm, I am clueless, it should work... Try changing the linktext to Xpath, but its my last guess...

Comment: another guess. what does `.isDisplayed()` and `.isEnabled()` say? Both should be true

Comment: The resulting html code could be useful, too. Although it seems that this is ok... Are there any `<iframe>` elements on your page? Btw stuck means "Throws an exception that it can't find the element," or "Does nothing at all"?

Comment: The browser does not do anything until you kill it.

Comment: Another thing: which web driver is it? Have you tried the test in another web driver, just to see if it is anything to do with a specific browser?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code check how many links are present on page if it contains your logout link then you can click on it by using locator "linktext".

```
public void Link(){

        driver.get(baseUrl);
        HtmlTagFinder links = LinkFinder.links();
        List<WebElement> allLinks = (List<WebElement>) links.findFrom(driver);
        System.out.println(allLinks.size());
        int i = 1;
        for(WebElement link : allLinks){
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(link.getText());
            i++;
        }

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("@value='Logout'")).click();
```

Comment: This is not a working one. Did you mean `By.xpath("//*[@value='Logout']")`?